# GaussianFilter Slow Behaviour when std. Deviation in set to 0

Tags: performance-tuning, convolution, resource-management

The problem occurs when setting the $\sigma$ of the `GaussianFilter` to zero and using the method `Method -> "Gaussian"`.

*The problem occurs here*

```
GaussianFilter[RandomReal[1, {12, 101, 101}], {4 {.1, 0, 0}+ 1, {.1, 0, 0}},
  {2, 0, 0}, Padding -> "Periodic", Method -> "Gaussian"];
```

If we set the `Method -> "Bessel"` or if we set the $\sigma$ very low (something like 0.125) the computation is very fast.

*Method Bessel fixes this*

```
GaussianFilter[RandomReal[1, {12, 101, 101}], {4 {.1, 0, 0} + 1, {.1, 0, 0}},
  {2, 0, 0}, Padding -> "Periodic", Method -> "Bessel"];
```

*Setting $\sigma$ to a non zero*

```
GaussianFilter[RandomReal[1, {12, 101, 101}], {4 {.1, 0.125, 0.125}+ 1, {.1, 0.125, 0.125}},
  {2, 0, 0}, Padding -> "Periodic", Method -> "Gaussian"];
```

**My Question is:** Is this expected behavior or are we dealing with a bug? And can you explain why this is happening?

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag until your observations have been confirmed by other users.

Comment: Ok, was not aware of that. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Timing

We can chart the effectiveness of the two methods with `RepeatedTiming[]`

```
range = {3, 5, 7, 10, 15, 20, 30, 40, 50};
bes = RepeatedTiming[
     GaussianFilter[
      RandomReal[
       1, {Round[#/3], #, #}], {4 {.1, 0, 0} + 1, {.1, 0, 0}}, {2, 0, 
       0}, Padding -> "Periodic", Method -> "Bessel"], 2][[1]] & /@ 
  range;
gauss = RepeatedTiming[
     GaussianFilter[
      RandomReal[
       1, {Round[#/3], #, #}], {4 {.1, 0, 0} + 1, {.1, 0, 0}}, {2, 0, 
       0}, Padding -> "Periodic", Method -> "Gaussian"], 2][[1]] & /@ 
  range;
ListLogPlot[{Transpose[{range, bes}], Transpose[{range, gauss}]}, 
 Joined -> True]
```

[image]

You can see that at `i=50`, the computation time climbs rapidly towards `10s` and beyond. Compare this with a `2d` version:

```
range2d = 10 range;
bes2d = RepeatedTiming[
     GaussianFilter[RandomReal[1, {#, #}], {{.1, 0, 0}}, {2, 0, 0}, 
      Padding -> "Periodic", Method -> "Bessel"], 2][[1]] & /@ range2d
gauss2d = RepeatedTiming[
     GaussianFilter[RandomReal[1, {#, #}], {{.1, 0, 0}}, {2, 0, 0}, 
      Padding -> "Periodic", Method -> "Gaussian"], 2][[1]] & /@ range2d
ListLogPlot[{Transpose[{range2d, bes2d}], Transpose[{range2d, gauss2d}]}, 
 Joined -> True]
```

[image]

If you increase the array sizes even further, the two lines become indistinguishable.

In other words, don't use `Gaussian` with `(3+)d` arrays.

### So what's going on?

When we run without `δ`

```
GaussianFilter[
  RandomReal[1, {12, 101, 101}], {4 {.1, 0, 0} + 1, {.1, 0, 0}}, {2, 
   0, 0}, Padding -> "Periodic", Method -> "Gaussian"][[1, 1]]
```

Which gives a result like:

> `-0.558742 + (0.0931892 (0. + 14.7756 DiracDelta[0]^2))/DiracDelta[0]^2`

This is an analytical result.

Whereas

```
GaussianFilter[
  RandomReal[
   1, {12, 101, 101}], {4 {.1, 10^-5, 10^-5} + 1, {.1, 10^-5, 
    10^-5}}, {2, 0, 0}, Padding -> "Periodic", 
  Method -> "Gaussian"][[1, 1]]
```

> `{-0.395175, 0.0122412,..., 0.469736, -0.102494}`

Yields a numeric result. Something which produces underflow when the `δ` comes close to `0`, meaning a numeric evaluation cannot be done when `δ=0`, which in higher dimensions causes a significant time increase.

This might mean that with a numeric evaluation you lose the added accuracy of the `Gaussian` method.

Comment: Thanks for you extensive research on the timing. I do want to add that the precision of the Gaussian is better

Comment: @FrankMartin Then it's not that peculiar that it takes longer :). Your example takes my computer `6.72714s` to run, which isn't excessive I think.

Comment: It seems odd to me that when you set the $ \sigma $ to zero the computation time is longer compared when you set $\sigma$ to 0.125, I would expect the opposite.

Comment: @FrankMartin And it is odd this just happens in 2-d. Nonetheless, maybe my edit to my answer gives some more insight.

Comment: Yes that definitely helps, it gives some insight in how Mathematica is dealing with this internally. For now I'll use a small sigma as a work around.